# Ubuntu 18.04 Apache2.4.29 not able to open ports other than 80

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-18.04

As stated in title, I have LAMP configuration with Apache2.4.29, the problem is when I open a new port other than 80(in this case, port 12743), it could not be accessed through edge browser as port 80 does.
I added a line here under /etc/apache2/ports.conf:
[image: ports.conf]

appended a paragraph under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
[image: 000-default.conf]

after that I used the following command to restart Apache2:
[image]
all these shows no warning nor error messages.

The Ubuntu currently has ufw inactive, and used iptables and fail2ban instead:
[image]

however, attempts to access the website via new port failed returning the following page:
[image]

I wonder what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, what I needed was just a sudo reboot.
It turned out that adding ports shall require not only an Apache2 restart but also a server reboot.